# Is "getting yourself being told to" a valid sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, american-english

> Imagine constantly getting yourself being told to do something.

Is the above a valid sentence? The question is particularly about the part "getting yourself being" in this context. This phrase describes a hypothetical situation that the author of the phrase is trying to create in the imagination of the person to whom this sentence is addressed and the person in this imaginary situation found himself hearing talk of 3-rd person.

Comment: You need to give us a complete sample sentence, in context.

Comment: I have explained all the context in the description. That's the entire context, there is no more context.

Comment: As a standalone sentence, it sounds bizarre. Unless there is additional context that explains why it's constructed the way it is, I would say it should be: *Imagine being constantly told to do something.* What's the purpose of *getting yourself*? Do you mean something like *imagine constantly* ***allowing*** *yourself to be told what to do*? But without anything coming before or after it, it still doesn't make sense. In response, I might say, "Okay, I've imagined it. And? What's your point?"

Comment: "Constantly being told" works. "Constantly getting yourself told" is a bit odd, but seems to imply that the person does something to provoke the 'telling'. "Getting yourself being told" doesn't work, though.

Comment: do you mean "Imagine constantly finding yourself being told to do something."?

Comment: This is correct within the context of a game or other hypothetical situation.

Comment: So that sentence appeared in your mail one day, with no return address???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no this isn't valid

> Imagine constantly getting yourself being told to do something.

If I was to re-word this is would replace getting with finding so:

> Imagine constantly **finding** yourself being told to do something.

Getting involves an action from the person you are doing something to cause this, whereas finding is more passive you just spot it happening (I think).

If you do mean the "being told to do something" is because of the persons own actions, that is completely different.